# Generating Captions from the Images Using Python (and Pythia)

Tags: python, nlp

some months ago I stumbled upon [this article on SEJ](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/generate-text-from-images-with-python/324001/) explaining how to generate captions from images using Python and Pythia framework.
The script used to work fine until some months ago. You can find the [original copy here in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1vzrxDYB0vxtuUy8KCaGxm--nDCJvyBSg). However, at some point, Pythia repository in Git was redirect to [MMF framework](https://github.com/facebookresearch/mmf) and the script stopped working. Colab returns the following error:

```
<ipython-input-9-b64f6c325603> in <module>()
 34 
 35 
 ---> 36 from pythia.utils.configuration import ConfigNode
 37 from pythia.tasks.processors import VocabProcessor, CaptionProcessor
 38 from pythia.models.butd import BUTD
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pythia'
```

Replacing this line of code with:

```
from mmf.utils.configuration import ConfigNode
from mmf.datasets.processors import BaseProcessor
from mmf.models.base_model import BaseModel
from mmf.common.registry import registry
from mmf.common.sample import Sample, SampleList
```

The script goes on for a little bit, but it stops again on these two errors:

```
 ---> 32 from maskrcnn_benchmark.config import cfg
 33 from maskrcnn_benchmark.layers import nms
 34 from maskrcnn_benchmark.modeling.detector import build_detection_model
 ----> 4 from yacs.config import CfgNode as CN
```

Right now I am stucked at this point.
Does anyone has an idea of which workaround might be the right resolution for this script?
Thank you